# use Object.keys to get properties which are used to create instances of a constructor then prints inherited properties

Tags: javascript

i am trying to send properties of an object using `Object.keys` and store it in a variable.So now i have an array containing two elements which are supposed to be instance of Person class and have a name property inherited.But arr[0] gives me `p1` but `arr[0].name` which is equivalent to `p1.name` doesn't print its name but shouldn't it??I want to know what is happening behind the scene??thanks!!!

```
(function(){
function Person(name){
   this.name=name;
}
var obj={
 'p1':new Person('person1'),
 'p2':new Person('person2')
};
var arr=Object.keys(obj);

console.log(arr[0].name);
})();
```

Comment: You should read about what `Object.keys` really does. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

Comment: `arr[0]` contains the string `p1` so you're actually checking for  `"p1".name`

Comment: Object keys returns an array of strings, not instances.

Comment: Yeah, always read the documentation before you use an unfamiliar method.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`arr` is an array of strings with the value `["p1", "p2"]` (or *possibly* `["p2", "p1"]`, since object properties are not ordered). Therefore, `arr[0].name` is equivalent to `"p1".name`, which unsurprisingly gives an `undefined` result.

`Object.keys(obj)` returns an *array of strings* where each string is the name of a property on `obj`. Here, `obj` has two properties, `p1` and `p2`, so `Object.keys(obj)` returns an array with two strings.

Instead, do `obj[arr[0]].name`, or more cleanly:

```
var indexZeroPropertyName = arr[0];
var firstObject = obj[indexZeroPropertyName];
console.log(firstObject.name)
```